# Piped Set Operation in REDIS

Tags: redis, set, pipe, multiset

Is it possible to compute multiset opeartion in redis using pipes 
i.e to say

(a union b union c) intersect (d union c) 
 SUNION  a b c  SINTER d c

Answer (score 3):

No, because in a pipeline you only get results once the entire set of commands is sent (see [documentation](http://redis.io/topics/pipelining)), ergo as you probably guessed you need to fetch the result of each nested operation in your example separately.

Something very similar however can be achieved using the scripting capability built in redis 2.6 with some lua, and it sounds like this could fit your bill:

```
EVAL "return redis.call('sinter', redis.call('sunion', 'a', redis.call('sunion', 'b', 'c')), redis.call('sunion', 'd', 'c'))"
```

The code above is a simplification and it's untested, but it should give you a rough idea of what's possible. More info on the documentation [here](http://redis.io/commands/eval).

Comment: Thanks Mahn, however it seems that this functionality is supported only from redis 2.6 which is still not committed as stable release

Comment: @raviop531 did you consider accepting the answer? Just saying, since there is no other answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can use trancastions (MULTI)

```
MULTI
SUNIONSTORE abc a b c
SUNIONSTORE cd c d
SINTERSTORE i abc cd 
SMEMBERS i
DEL abc cd i
EXEC
```

p.s But it seems like you dont need to use **c** becouse after all its members will placed in **i**

Comment: Won't work, the premise of a multi-exec block is that everything is run only once exec is issued, which means the third `SINTERSTORE` cannot access `abc` or `cd` within the same transaction, because the previous `SUNIONSTORE` have not been processed yet.